# How can I make the hover text fit within the box? Using Bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

[CODEPEN](https://s.codepen.io/minacosentino/debug/yPyRjG/vPAKKVQGjnmA)

I'm trying to have the text that appears on hover show fully within the box. The mixture of 1) having the hover effect with content, 2) using the level/level-item, and 3) wanting to create an equal vertical centering within the box is making this a bit complicated. Below is a screenshot of how the text is overflowing to the right. Please note, I have to achieve this using pure CSS.

[image]

Currently I have the following code:

```css
.hover-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.showme {
  display: none;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.hover-box:hover .showme {
  display: inline;
}

.hover-box:hover .ok {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns has-text-centered">
  <div class="column is-paddingless border height">
    <div class="level hover-box has-text-centered">
      <div class="level-item">
        <p class="showme is-size-5 has-text-white has-text-centered">State the purpose and importance of conversation</p>
        <p class="ok is-size-1 has-text-white title is-uppercase">Open</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Comparing the given code with the screenshot provided it looks like you're missing some styles. Could you add all applicable styles that will replicate the issue as closely as possible?

Comment: Hi @UncaughtTypeError, I added a CodePen, but I think some of those styles might be from the Bulma documentation (which I have linked as a stylesheet in CodePen).

Comment: Have you tried adding `flex-direction: column;` to `.hover-box`?

Comment: You're the best!! That worked perfectly - thank you so much. I'm a bit of a noob, so i appreciate it :)

Comment: Don't mention it - we all start somewhere ;)